# Box2D changing the angle a circle is facing without moving the circle

Tags: c++, math, box2d, angle

I am using Box2D to create a simple game and I would want to achieve something like this:

I have a circle with an "arrow" pointing to it's current angle. On a keyboard click, the angle will increment a value and the angle of the circle will change as per seen in the second picture below.
[image: Initial Circle, where angle of the Circle = 0]

The initial state of the circle, where the angle of the circle = 0. The line is pointing at 0 degrees.

[image: Final Circle, where angle of the Circle = 15]

This is the next state of the circle after a keyboard click from the user. The angle of the circle is now 15 degrees.

To do the transformation, I have done something like this:

```
void MyCirclecle::turnBall(float angle)
{
    body_->SetTransform( body_->GetWorldPoint( b2Vec2(0,0) ), body_->GetAngle() + (angle * b2_pi/180)); 
}
```

The circle is turning in the correct direction, but the circle is moving at the same time. On each click, it will move slightly up or right, and after 180 degrees, it will move slightly down or left. Eventually after 360 degrees, it will be placed slightly on top of the initial state. I have also tried using `body_->GetWorldCenter()` and `body_->GetPosition()` for the first parameter of the `SetTransform`, but I am still getting the same thing. Is there any way that I could do, to not move the circle but can change the angle it is facing?

Comment: I think the problem is that the centre of your complex shape is not the centre of the circle but rather the centre of the shape defined by both the circle and the line. Try drawing a marker at the centre of the complex shape. Have you tried using a revolute joint instead?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the angle of a circle at a body relative position of `b2Vec2(0, 0)` without linearly moving it is accomplished with the `MyCircle::turnBall` method implemented as:

```
void MyCirclecle::turnBall(float angle)
{
    body_->SetTransform( body_->GetPosition(), body_->GetAngle() + (angle * b2_pi/180)); 
}
```

That you're seeing the circle linearly moving as you've described however suggests that the circle isn't at the body relative position of `b2Vec2(0, 0)`. Somewhere somehow your circle shape's position has gotten moved away from the body's origin.

At least in Box2D 2.3.2, a `b2CircleShape` shape's constructor sets the `m_p` member variable (via `m_p.SetZero();`) so that it's at the body's origin. So I suspect that either your code is explicitly changing the `m_p` value or you have some memory corruption going on (that's changing it for you).

OTOH, if what you really want is a way to rotate the circle at its relative offset (whatever that may be) from its body (so moving the body while the circle only rotates), you'll want `MyCircle::turnBall` method implemented more like this:

```
void MyCirclecle::turnBall(float rotate_amount)
{
    const float rotate_amount_in_rads = rotate_amount * b2_pi / 180;
    const float c = cos(rotate_amount_in_rads);
    const float s = sin(rotate_amount_in_rads);

    const b2Vec2 pivot_point = body_->GetWorldPoint(circle_shape_.m_p);
    const b2Transform xfm = body_->GetTransform();
    const b2Vec2 p = xfm.p - pivot_point;
    const float x = p.x * c - p.y * s;
    const float y = p.x * s + p.y * c;

    const b2Vec2 pos = b2Vec2(x, y) + pivot_point;
    const float angle = xfm.q.GetAngle() + rotate_amount_in_rads;
    body_->SetTransform(pos, angle);
}
```